# Text Mining an Outlook Email Archive

Tags: outlook, text-mining

I am considering preforming some text-mining on a set of large individual .pst file containing >4 years of communication.

Initially, I would like to just extract the header information to identify social networks, but ultimately would like to begin to classify emails based on key-words or create some structured output that would support some further analysis.

Does anyone have any suggestions where to begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the research done on the publicly available [Enron Email Dataset](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~enron/) -> The page has link to some interesting papers